# Ways to update p:dataTable after delete method?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm looking for ways to update p:dataTable after running delete method. In my case a user is expected to fill p:dataTable first with a parametrized search. Table contains rows that can be cancelled using delete  method. This doesn't mean that they are deleted completely, delete method rather just changes some columns in db table. For example changes hasCancellationReference column to true. Now this means that I need the table still be shown on dataTable row, just with a changed status. Now I'm looking for the correct way to implement dataTable refresh after delete method.

My dataTable and delete button:

```
   <h:form prependId="false" rendered="#{myController.lst ne null and myController.lst.size() gt 0}" id="dataTable">  
              <p:dataTable value="#{myController.lzy}" lazy="true" var="tra" rows="10" paginator="true" id="dtas"
                           selectionMode="single" selection="#{myController.cur}" rowKey="#{tra.transactionId}"   
                           paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                           paginatorPosition="top"
                           rowsPerPageTemplate="10,25,50">
                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{myController.receipt}" update="#{parent}:tradlg" process="@this" global="false" oncomplete="PF('tradlg').show()"/>
                <p:ajax event="page" update=""/>
                <p:column headerText="Timestamp" width="30">
                  <h:outputText value="#{path.toGet.myTimeVariable}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss" timeZone="EET"/>
                  </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Line" width="10">
                  <h:outputText value="#{var.lineCode}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Stop" width="60">
                  <h:outputText value="#{var.stopCode} #{var.stopName}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Vechicle" width="30">
                  <h:outputText value="#{var.vehicleNumber}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Status" width="40">
                  <h:outputText value="Deleted" style="color: red" rendered="#{var.hasCancellationReference eq true}"/>           
                  <p:commandButton  value="Delete" 
                  action="#{emvController.deleteTransaction(tra.transitAccount, tra.transactionId)}" 
                  rendered="#{tra.hasCancellationReference eq false}"/>
                </p:column>

              </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>
```

Things i have tried:

1. Running search method inside delete method in backend code:

   ```
      public void deleteRow(int var, String varId) {

    try {
      MyParameterClass.getInstance().deleteRow(var, varId);
      message = MyParameterClass.getInstance().getMessage();
      if (message.equals("success 200")) {
        successMsg();
        //If delete was succesfull run searchMethod
        searchMethod();
      } else {
        errorMsg();
        System.out.println("Faces Message Controller: " + message);
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(EmvController.class).error(ex);
      return;
    }
   ```

   }
2. Doing plain refresh on page after delete method. This does work, but i suspect will cause problems with new features I plan to implement in the future.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490281/pdatatable-not-updating-after-deleting-row See if this helps :)

Comment: "Doing plain refresh on page after delete method. This does work, but i suspect will cause problems with new features I plan to implement in the future." This kind of makes it impossible to answer your question.

Comment: @JasperdeVries so it is impossible to just update the table?

Comment: I would set a `widgetVar` on the table and use that in the `oncomplete` of the `commandButton` to do `PF('myWidgetVar').filter()`.

Comment: If the underlying data(model) is changed as a result of the deleteTransaction() call in the `p:commandButton`, wouldn't it be enough to add `update="dtas"` to the commandButton so that the dataTable component is refreshed after the ajax call?